# Raspbian Fix for Chrome "did not shut down properly"

Tags: linux, shell, google-chrome, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I need a quick and dirty fix for chrome did not shutdown properly in linux. I'm running concerto digital signage in chrome in kiosk mode, but if I hard unplug the system, or we lose power I have to take a mouse and keyboard out to get rid of the bar. Shell script or what have you would be just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly": false/"exited_cleanly": true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

This may be a doable solution... testing it now.